# R parse a string to extract, calculate, and replace a number

Tags: r, string, parsing, replace

I have a one-column matrix with variables concatenated together for input to a computer system. Some rows, but not all, have a number I need to extract, reduce by 5%, then replace in the string. I'd like to avoid a for loop - is this an `lapply` kind of thing?

Given this subset of data:

```
1989-05-04 [Maize].Sow(cultivar: B_100, population: 6, depth: 50, rowSpacing: 762)
1989-06-26 [Fertiliser].Apply(Amount: 124, Type: NO3N)
1989-10-23 [Maize].Harvest
```

for only the rows that have [Fertiliser] in them, I need to extract the number following "Amount:", in this case 124. Then I need to multiply it by 0.95 and replace it. The end result should be this:

```
1989-05-04 [Maize].Sow(cultivar: B_100, population: 6, depth: 50, rowSpacing: 762)
1989-06-26 [Fertiliser].Apply(Amount: 117.8, Type: NO3N)
1989-10-23 [Maize].Harvest
```

Here's a data frame:

```
field_ops <- data.frame(V1=c("1989-05-04 [Maize].Sow(cultivar: B_100, population: 6, depth: 50, rowSpacing: 762)","1989-06-26 [Fertiliser].Apply(Amount: 124, Type: NO3N)","1989-10-23 [Maize].Harvest"))
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option using `tidyverse`, where we can extract the value after `Amount:`, convert to numeric, do the calculation, convert back to character, then replace that value in the column for rows that have `Fertiliser`.

```
library(tidyverse)

field_ops %>% 
  mutate(x = as.character(as.numeric(str_extract(V1, "(?i)(?<=Amount:\\D)\\d+"))*0.95),
         V1 = ifelse(str_detect(V1, "Fertiliser"), str_replace(V1,"(?i)(?<=Amount:\\D)\\d+", x), V1)) %>% 
  select(-x)
```

**Output**

```
    V1
1 1989-05-04 [Maize].Sow(cultivar: B_100, population: 6, depth: 50, rowSpacing: 762)
2                           1989-06-26 [Fertiliser].Apply(Amount: 117.8, Type: NO3N)
3                                                         1989-10-23 [Maize].Harvest
```

Or we could use just `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)

str_replace(field_ops$V1,
            "(?i)(?<=Amount:\\D)\\d+",
            as.character(as.numeric(
              str_extract(field_ops$V1, "(?i)(?<=Amount:\\D)\\d+")
            ) * 0.95))
```